# Disable Notification Pop Up in Status Bar Notification in Nougat

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-7.1-nougat, android-statusbar, notification-listener

I am using `NotificationListenerService` to clear the notification as soon as it is posted. I am using the following code to achieve it.

```
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        NotificationListener.this.cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.e("Msg", "Notification Removed");

    }
}
```

Everything is working fine and notification is removed from Status Bar but as soon as a text message notification is posted, **Status Bar shows a pop up notification before cancelling the notification** in case of Android Nougat. Check the screenshot for better understanding.

[image: screenshot when notification is posted]

Now my question is about how to stop this pop up from popping on Status Bar before notification is cancelled?

Comment: did you try this in `if(packageName.equals("com.my.package")){
        mNotificationManager.cancel(yourNotificationId);
        return;
    }` in  `onNotificationPosted`

Comment: @SantanuSur Thanks for suggesting but that doesn't help as notification is not generated by my app. It is generated by OS or some other app.

Comment: did you try `notificationManager.cancelAll();` if it works let me know

Comment: @SantanuSur already tried this but it produces same result.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @LavanyaVelusamy no solutions yet

Comment: **try this**                                                                                                            
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
 _cancelNotification(sbn.getPackageName(), sbn.getTag(), sbn.getId());_
        } 
 else {

           _cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());_

        }